# Why float "division-by-zero" exception wasn't caught in a function even handler was set?

Tags: c, libc

I've tried to learn the signal handling in C, when found strange behaviour. 
When x /= y; executed in the context of the main function the signal handler works. But when the same executed in some function (bad_func) handler is ignored however signal handler for SIGFPE is already set.

Q: Why SIGFPE wasn't caught in a function by my global signal handler even _control87 was called?

(MS VC 2010):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <float.h>

jmp_buf g_jb_MainFunc;

void hook_zd (int i)
{
    printf("Result :%i\n",i);
    longjmp(g_jb_MainFunc, 5);
}
void bad_func(void)
{
    double x = 0., y = 0.;
    puts("hello1");
    //abort();
    x /= y;
    puts("bye1");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double x = 0., y = 0.;
    signal(SIGFPE, hook_zd);
    signal(SIGABRT, hook_zd);
    puts("hello");
    _control87(0, _MCW_EM );
    int res;
    if (! (res = setjmp(g_jb_MainFunc)))
    {
        //abort();
        //x /= y;
        bad_func();
    } else
    {
        printf("Jumped here from: %i\n",res);
    }
    puts("bye");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_control87` is for floating-point only, integer operations are an entirely different thing.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://blogs.amd.com/developer/tag/mxcsr-registe/

Comment: GMan: On Unix setting float control word is related to integer divide-by-zero too. So "float" name is from backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me unless I compile with optimizations turned on.  For example, if I compile it from the command line as `cl mysigtest.cpp`, the exceptions work as expected.  But if I compile it `cl /O1 mysigtest.cpp`, then it does not show the exception.

The disassembled code shows the problem:

```
?bad_func@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl bad_func(void)):
  00000000: 68 00 00 00 00     push        offset ??_C@_06CKBHOFLC@hello1?$AA@
  00000005: E8 00 00 00 00     call        _puts
  0000000A: 68 00 00 00 00     push        offset ??_C@_04EEFJMNKA@bye1?$AA@
  0000000F: E8 00 00 00 00     call        _puts
  00000014: 83 C4 08           add         esp,8
  00000017: C3                 ret
```

The division has been optimized out.  Try it with optimizations turned off, or change `bad_func` to the following.  For me, it "defeated" the optimizer:

```
double bad_func(double y)
{
    double x = 0.; 
    puts("hello1");
    //abort();
    x /= y;
    puts("bye1");
    return x;
}
```

And change the call to it:

```
bad_func( 0.0 );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it on asm level, if this is due to optimization!

Comment: Nice! It's also good to add _fpreset(); before longjmp in hook_zd, if we want to continue execution after SIGFPE. Otherway the program crashes in my environment next time FPU is used.